# External .json file to Javascript variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-maps

I'm currently working on a project that implements google maps with old map overlayers and polylines from json files.
The json files are stored externally and I need to get the content of that file into a javascript variable in order implement it on google maps.
I've tried a lot of things with ajax and jquery, but I can't get it to work.

The json file is located here: http://www.criva.be/project/modules/browse/json/Brits_1918.json

Answer (score 1):

This will work only if the page with the javascript is on the same domain, i.e. www.criva.be otherwise you need to use JSONP

Comment: thx for the solution, when i put the file in a local folder, it works on my localhost (WAMP). But stil nothing on my actual server where criva.be is hosted...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use JSON.parse()..do an ajax call to your url and with the result do,

```
var brits = JSON.parse(results)
```

then you'll ba able to use dot notation,

```
console.log(brits.type)
```

http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prefixing your json definition with a JavaScript `var` declaration and then just loading the file directly, treated as a JavaScript file?

You could add this to the `<head>` of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json/Brits_1918.json"></script>
```

And then add this to the front of your `Brits_1918.json` file:

```
var featureCollection =  {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [ ... ]
}
```

The browser should then load the json file, the JavaScript parser built into the browser should parse it, and assign it to the global `var` named: `featureCollection`.